# Posting data with PHP Curl not working

Tags: php, curl

First of all, I am new to Curl. I am trying to post the form data directly to the processing file process.php. But it is not working.
My form is below

```
<!-- bla.html-->
<html>
<body>
    <form action="process.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

And the process.php file is

```
<?php
   echo $name=$_POST['name'];
?>
```

I tried to pass the data from a file called curl.php. Which is below

```
<?php
$url="http://localhost/test/process.php";

$data=array('name=raheem');

$ch = curl_init();

                // $ch = curl_init(); 
                curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
                curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
                //curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
                curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
                curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
                curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
                //curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
                curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

                curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
                curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
                echo $result = curl_exec ($ch);
?>
```

It displays correctly. But i need to login first before passing the name to the process.php file. I wrote the below code. But it's not working.

```
<?php

    $username="myuser"; 
    $password="mypass"; 
    $url="http://localhost/test/login.php"; 
    //$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

    $postdata = "txtuname=".$username."&txtpass=".$password;

    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
    //curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    //curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    $result = curl_exec ($ch); 
    if($result) {
            $url="http://localhost/test/process.php";

            $data="name=raheem&email=raheem@gmail.com";

            $ch = curl_init();

                            // $ch = curl_init(); 
                            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
                            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
                            //curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
                            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
                            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
                            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
                            //curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
                            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

                            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
                            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
                            echo $result = curl_exec ($ch);
    }


?>
```

Here, the login.php will take username and password and redirect to the bla.html if the user exists. But it's not working. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: [`curl_close()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-close.php)

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Is the code being executed? Is it returning an error?

Comment: Not showing any error

Comment: Can i login manually and do the rest by code?

Comment: I used curl_close();

Comment: Any reason you've commented out the cookiejar? Did you make sure the cookiejar file is writable?